# Get particular variable from curl response string

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway, php-5.3, php-curl

I am getting the response from curl as follows in a string:

```
Accepted=AVSAUTH:TEST:::829649376:N::U
ENTRYMETHOD=KEYED
historyid=829649376
MERCHANTORDERNUMBER=14700000186
orderid=646526156
PAYTYPE=MasterCard
recurid=0
refcode=829649376-TEST
result=1
Status=Accepted
transid=0
```

I want to get individual variables like status= Accepted so that i can able to store those in my database. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

preg_match is your friend:

```
<?
$result = "Accepted=AVSAUTH:TEST:::829649376:N::U
ENTRYMETHOD=KEYED
historyid=829649376
MERCHANTORDERNUMBER=14700000186
orderid=646526156
PAYTYPE=MasterCard
recurid=0
refcode=829649376-TEST
result=1
Status=Accepted
transid=0";

preg_match_all("/^([^=]+)=(.*)$/m", $result, $regs, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$data = [];
foreach($regs as $reg) {
    $data[$reg[1]] = $reg[2];
}

print_r($data);
?>
```

$data will be an hash Array:

```
Array
(
    [Accepted] => AVSAUTH:TEST:::829649376:N::U
    [ENTRYMETHOD] => KEYED
    [historyid] => 829649376
    [MERCHANTORDERNUMBER] => 14700000186
    [orderid] => 646526156
    [PAYTYPE] => MasterCard
    [recurid] => 0
    [refcode] => 829649376-TEST
    [result] => 1
    [Status] => Accepted
    [transid] => 0
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mats, u rock

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be to loop over each line, and build it into a simple key/value array:

```
$results = [];

foreach (explode("\n", $string) as $line) {
  list ($key, $value) = explode('=', $line, 2);
  $results[$key] = $value;
}

echo $results['Status']; // Accepted
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract content of curl response as follows,

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
// ... 

$response = curl_exec($ch); // Curl response

// After your curl response
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($body);
```